# Modify a MYSQL query to select only specific rows, used as a sort of index

Tags: php, mysql, forum

I'm writing a search form for a simple forum, but I cannot manage to find a solution to select only the fields that interest me. The forum table, named "Messages" (MySql) uses this structure:

```
MessageID - FirstMsg - Content
201 - 0 - Jack and Rose
202 - 201 - Rose
203 - 201 - Jack, Rose, David
204 - 0 - Bill
205 - 204 - Rose
206 - 0 - Rose and David
207 - 206 - David
```

The main problem is that the php forum page that I'm using recognize the messages with FirstMsg 0 as "parent" and the ones with FirstMsg different from 0 as replies to the one with 0 and MessageID equal to their FirstMsg.

es. row with 201 as MessageID 201 is parent of 202 and 203 that will be viewed as replies to post 201.

With a MySql query and php I easily get the content:

```
$MySql = "SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE Content LIKE '%$Search%'" ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1, 30";
$Result = mysql_query($MySql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) {

}
```

For example, searching Rose I get, echoing the content in the while loop:

```
201 - 0 - Jack and Rose
202 - 201 - Rose
203 - 201 - Jack, Rose, David
205 - 204 - Rose
206 - 0 - Rose and David
```

When i need to get, with a query, only the "parent" elements, even of "Rose" is nor present in the parent message but only in one of the replies, like:

```
201 - 0 - Jack and Rose
204 - 0 - Bill
206 - 0 - Rose and David
```

It is possible to do this changing only the MySql query? I need that because the query itself is used, among  the same page, to navigate between the “pages” generated by the php when their count increases after the max messages per page number. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In future please take the time to format the code in your question appropriately (using the "{}" editor control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to get the parent messages:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM Messages m JOIN Messages p
    ON m.FirstMsg = p.MessageID
        OR (m.FirstMsg = 0 AND m.MessageID = p.MessageID)
WHERE m.Content LIKE '%$Search%'
ORDER BY m.Date DESC LIMIT 1, 30
```

If you want to sort by the parent message, change `m.Date` to `p.Date`

Comment: I've tried the code but I get a lot of duplicate answers. Is possible to avoid them? Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Thanks, now it works fine. It requires a lot of time to complete the query, is that normal?

Comment: Unless you use full text search, its going to take time.

Comment: How I use a full text search?

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to filter out the results like this:

```
 - set finalResultSet as nothing
 - if the FirstMsg = 0 : then union MessageID with finalResultSet
 - else : union FirstMsg with finalResultSet
```

You could do the filtering part in PHP with the above conditions.

To filter it in mysql, I was thinking of something like this:

```
(
    SELECT MessageID FROM Messages
    WHERE 
        FirstMsg=0 AND
        Content LIKE '%$Search%'
    ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1, 30
)
UNION
(
    SELECT FirstMsg FROM Messages
    WHERE 
        Content LIKE '%$Search%'
    ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1, 30
)
```

Highly inefficient. I aint good at MySQL queries. But you surely get the idea, dont you? Plus, I am sure, there are many experts around here who will suggest a better solution. Good luck! :-)

Comment: In php I did the filtering, and it worked, but the main problem was that I could not use it to navigate between pages. The mysql don't gets, strangely, any row as a result. Still, thanks for your answer :)